# ContextMenu that shows/hides items based on DataGrid's selections?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, contextmenu, resourcedictionary

I have a context menu set as a resource dictionary (because it can't be a user control):

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="Test.FooGridContextMenu"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ContextMenu x:Key="FooGridContextMenu" ContextMenuOpening="OnContextMenuOpening">

    </ContextMenu>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and I use it for a data grid:

```
<DataGrid ContextMenu="{DynamicResource FooGridContextMenu}">...
```

The code behind for the context menu resource is this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class FooGridContextMenu : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public FooGridContextMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }  

        void OnContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("here i am");
        }
    }
}
```

Problems:

1) The event callback method is not getting called, i.e. I don't see "Here i am" logs.

2) How can I show / hide some of the context menu items based on complex logic in the opening event? Basically I am asking how can I access the data grid from the event callback to be able to retrieve the selected rows? I know how to set `Visibility`, but I don't know how to access the `DataGrid` to retrieve the selected models/rows.

3) Is `ResourceDictionary` the way to go here? I tried `UserControl` first, but it complains that `ContextMenu` cannot have a visual parent, so, I guess I can't use it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Shouldn't the ContextMenuOpening event be wired on the DataGrid itself?

Comment: @Dtex so you mean I should put it on the `DataGrid`, and let the grid handle the event and then let the grid show/hide its context menu items? Hmm. I figured the context menu should hide/show its items, after all the items belong to the context menu?

Comment: yes i mean <DataGrid ContextMenu="{DynamicResource FooGridContextMenu}" ContextMenuOpening="OnContextMenuOpening"> this will fix issue 1 i think.